# another win32 problem

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Having a problem here with creating a child window with c++ and win32 api.
If i check the getLastError function its returning "87" but i dont know what that means.
For what i know my code does not contain errors, can someone take a look at my code and help me figure out whats wrong with it.

(This is in the WinProc WM_CREATE section.)

```
        HWND hChildWindow   =   CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,0,NULL,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,hwnd,0,GetModuleHandle(0),NULL);
    if(!hChildWindow)
    {
         char text[256];
             int errormsg = (int)GetLastError();
             sprintf(text,"Error# %i",errormsg);
             MessageBox(0,text,"Error",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);   
         return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[87 = Invalid Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) - be aware that you can use [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get a string message from an error code.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter to `CreateWindowEx` is a window class (either string or `ATOM`). Obviously `NULL` is not a valid value.

P.S.

> For what i know my code does not
>   contain errors...

Beware of such a loud phrases. When *something* doesn't work everything should be checked carefully. Otherwise you may just accuse something/someone without any good for solving the problem. Check everything vs standard/documentation/specifications/etc. before you make any judgement.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look through the [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28VS.85%29.aspx) reference indicates `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. You're most likely passing in an invalid combination of styles/flags to your window.